# Set-Service Automatic failing in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change the startup type of a service using PowerShell from *Manual* to *Automatic* and vice versa.

I was successful while changing to *Manual* with the following command:

```bsh
Set-Service -name $servicename -StartupType Manual
```

But while trying to change it to *Automatic*:

```bsh
Set-Service -name $servicename -StartupType Automatic
```

it is failing

```
Set-Service : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Automatic'.
At C:\Users\speedy\powershell\startall.ps1:34 char:4
+             Set-Service â€“name $servicename â€“StartupType Automatic
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, you used an "uncommon" minus sign to start a parameter. You probably copied the command from a badly formatted website or a word document. Make sure you use a hyphen (`-`, Unicode: 002D) to begin a parameter. It should be sufficient to press *minus* on your keyboard while using a basic texteditor or PowerShell itself.

Here are 4 different characters in one line to see the difference: - − – — ([read more](https://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/)). You need the first one.